# error on xml declaration

Tags: android

I get an error line under "one" in the line setContentView(R.layout.one); the error says "one cannot be resolved or is not an error field".  However, I am not being shown any error in my one.xml file.
I even cleaned the project a several times, but still it persists.
I even checked the R.java page's layout section and things were absolutely fine over there too.

Here is my xml page - "one" :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<RelativeLayout 

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/rel_layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/tapregister" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ashu" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and my class :

```
package ashish.com.example.game;

import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationSet;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Pageone extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.one);

    ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
    Animation anim1 = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 1024, 824);
    anim1.setDuration(3000);
    anim1.setFillAfter(true);

    anim1.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    Animation anim2 = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 824, 1024);
                    anim2.setDuration(3000);
                    anim2.setFillAfter(true);
                    imageView.clearAnimation();
                    imageView.startAnimation(anim2);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }
            });


    imageView.startAnimation(anim1);


}
}
```

Comment: Sorry just making sure that the one.xml file is in `res/layout` folder?

Answer (score 0):

If your Java class is in a sub-package, make sure to import the proper R file.

```
import {your top-level package}.R;
```

For example, if your project has the package "com.example.myapp" and your activity is in com.example.myapp.activities, you'll have to call

```
import com.example.myapp.R;
```

Right now, you are calling

```
import android.R;
```

which may be interfering with getting your layout.

Comment: Glad to hear it! If you mark the answer as accepted, it will help others with the same problem in the future.